# Cast error with Entity Framework and Lists in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list

I create a generic function to get a specific page for an EntityObject collection:

```
    public static IList<EntityObject> GetPageItemsOfCollection(IQueryable<EntityObject> collectionIQueryable,
                                                               int startIndex,
                                                               int pageSize)
    {
        if (collectionIQueryable == null)
            return null;

        return collectionIQueryable.Skip(startIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList();
    }
```

When I try to user this function like this:

```
IQueryable<EntityObjectSubClass> entityObjectSubClassIQueryable = GetEntityObjectSubClassIQueryableBySomeFilter(filter);


IList<EntityObjectSubClass> entityObjectSubClass = (IList<EntityObjectSubClass>) GetPageItemsOfCollection(entityObjectSubClassIQueryable, startIndex, pageSize)
```

Allways getting a cast error:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject]
>   to type System.Collections.Generic.IList[Models.EntityObjectSubClass].

Why this happen if the IList returned by the GetPageItemsOfCollection function contain elements of the EntityObjectSubClass type?

Comment: try using `OfType<T>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IList<EntityObjectSubClass>` will not inherit from `IList<EntityObjectClass>`, nor does it have the sort of contravariance that would allow this.

Consider that if we have an object that implements `IList<EntityObjectClass>`, there's no reason why it need not be full of `EntityObjectSomeOtherSubClass` objects. It is not capable of acting like `IList<EntityObjectSubClass>`, so it can't be cast to that.

Your best approach is perhaps to reduce the `GetPageItemsOfCollection` method down to doing the single task of obtaining a page, rather than of obtaining a page and putting it into a list:

```
 public static IQueryable<EntityObject> GetPageItemsOfCollection(IQueryable<EntityObject> collectionIQueryable, int startIndex, int pageSize)
{
  if (collectionIQueryable == null)
    return null;
  return collectionIQueryable.Skip(startIndex).Take(pageSize);
}
```

(Note that I return `IQueryable` rather than `IEnumerable`, you could opt to return `IEnumerable` instead, but there's no reason not to allow further Linq operations to be done against the original query provider, so that e.g. `GetPageItemsOfCollection(fromADB, 10, 10).Any()` could be executed fully on a database).

Then you could use the likes of:

```
GetPageItemsOfCollection(entityObjectSubClassIQueryable, startIndex, pageSize).Cast<EntityObjectSubClass>().ToList()
```

Of course, you could just use that anyway, without changing `GetPageItemsOfCollection`, but you'd be creating a list, just to throw it away again when you create the second list you actually want.

Comment: I try to use your advice but when invoking the function `GetPageItemsOfCollection(entityObjectSubClassIQueryable, startIndex, pageSize).Cast<EntityObjectSubClass>.ToList()`          I get the followig error: `Error 3 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Cast<TResult>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context` Could this because I using the entity framework 4.0 and not a more recent?

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo, `.Cast<EntityObjectSubClass>.ToList()` should have been `.Cast<EntityObjectSubClass>().ToList()`. I've fixed the code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`Cast<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method

```
GetPageItemsOfCollection(entityObjectSubClassIQueryable, startIndex,pageSize)
    .Cast<EntityObjectSubClass>.ToList();
```