# Specified cast is not valid in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a ASP.NET Core Web Application C# in Visual Studio 2019 using Oracle database and when I run it, it opens ok the home page, there's just on link on it, and when I click, it throws me an unhandled exception, specified cast is not valid.

**TipoProdutoRepository.cs** code:

```
using FiapSmartCity.Models;
using FiapSmartCity.Repository.Context;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace FiapSmartCity.Repository
{
    public class TipoProdutoRepository
    {

        private readonly DataBaseContext context;

        public TipoProdutoRepository()
        {
            context = new DataBaseContext();
        }
        public IList<TipoProduto> Listar()
        {
            return context.TipoProduto.ToList();
        }
        public TipoProduto Consultar(int id)
        {
            return context.TipoProduto.Find(id);
        }
        public void Inserir(TipoProduto tipoProduto)
        {
            context.TipoProduto.Add(tipoProduto);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        public void Alterar(TipoProduto tipoProduto)
        {
            context.TipoProduto.Update(tipoProduto);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        public void Excluir(int id)
        {      
            var tipoProduto = new TipoProduto()
            {
                IdTipo = id
            };
            context.TipoProduto.Remove(tipoProduto);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

error at:

```
return context.TipoProduto.ToList();
```

**TipoProdutoController.cs** code:

```
using FiapSmartCity.Models;
using FiapSmartCity.Repository;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
namespace FiapSmartCity.Controllers
{
    public class TipoProdutoController : Controller
    {
        private readonly TipoProdutoRepository tipoProdutoRepository;
        public TipoProdutoController()
        {
            tipoProdutoRepository = new TipoProdutoRepository();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var listaTipo = tipoProdutoRepository.Listar();
            return View(listaTipo);
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Cadastrar()
        {
            return View(new TipoProduto());
        }        
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Cadastrar(Models.TipoProduto tipoProduto)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                tipoProdutoRepository.Inserir(tipoProduto);
                @TempData["mensagem"] = "Tipo cadastrado com sucesso!";
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "TipoProduto");
            }
            else
            {
                return View(tipoProduto);
            }
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Editar(int Id)
        {
            var tipoProduto = tipoProdutoRepository.Consultar(Id);
            return View(tipoProduto);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Editar(Models.TipoProduto tipoProduto)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                tipoProdutoRepository.Alterar(tipoProduto);
                @TempData["mensagem"] = "Tipo alterado com sucesso!";
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "TipoProduto");
            }
            else
            {
                return View(tipoProduto);
            }
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Consultar(int Id)
        {
            var tipoProduto = tipoProdutoRepository.Consultar(Id);
            return View(tipoProduto);
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Excluir(int Id)
        {
            tipoProdutoRepository.Excluir(Id);
            @TempData["mensagem"] = "Tipo removido com sucesso!";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "TipoProduto");
        }
    }
}
```

error at:

```
var listaTipo = tipoProdutoRepository.Listar();
```

And here's the full exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetBoolean(Int32 i)
   at lambda_method(Closure , DbDataReader )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactory.Create(DbDataReader dataReader)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer)
   at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider._TrackEntities[TOut,TIn](IEnumerable`1 results, QueryContext queryContext, IList`1 entityTrackingInfos, IList`1 entityAccessors)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at FiapSmartCity.Repository.TipoProdutoRepository.Listar() in C:\Users\raphael\source\repos\FiapSmartCity\Repository\TipoProdutoRepository.cs:line 23
   at FiapSmartCity.Controllers.TipoProdutoController.Index() in C:\Users\raphael\source\repos\FiapSmartCity\Controllers\TipoProdutoController.cs:line 16
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Please separate your code and your error, this is unreadable

Comment: Ok, this is my first post here, and also my first project in visual studio, so I'm still a newbie in both. This is just the error that I posted, this small code in the error was in fact thrown together by visual studio. What should I do? Remove the code from the error and post the entire code for the two classes mentioned in the error, is that it?

Comment: just format your text a bit better, first paste your error, then add a couple of line breaks then add your code below

Comment: I did what you told me, I hope it's readable now.

Comment: @raphaelmsx,Does this help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935200/cast-error-with-entity-framework-and-lists-in-c-sharp ?

Comment: Show us `ToList()` implementation on `TipoProduto`.

Comment: What is the definition of DataBaseContext.TipoProduto please? it is probably something that can't be converted to a list.

Comment: @Polyfun you mean this:     public DbSet<TipoProduto> TipoProduto { get; set; }

Comment: @Fildor There's no mention of ```ToList()``` on ```TipoProduto``` ... I'll explain better: this is not really my code, it's on the texts of a online university I'm taking, and the people there take sooooo long (days) to reply, so I tried here.

Comment: Well, if it is not a memberfunction of `TipoProduto` then maybe it is in one of the classes in the inheritance tree or implemented as "Extension Method". If there is none at all, it should throw another exception. If you are in Visual Studio, you can try and point your cursor in ToList() and hit F12.

Comment: @Fildor ```public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source);```

Comment: DbSet implements IEnumerable<T>, so "return context.TipoProduto.ToList();" should be OK. You really need to post the full details of the exception.

Comment: @Polyfun ok, just edited the OP with the full exception.

Comment: I think your TipoProduto model has a bool property that EF is mapping onto a column in your Oracle table that cannot be converted to a boolean value.

Comment: @Polyfun That did it !! The column in Oracle table is ```CHAR(1)```, so I changed the EF mapping to ```Char``` and it's running ok now! Thanks!

Comment: Apparently the `i` argument is a column index per https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/OracleDataReaderClass.htm#CHDGEBAJ (and this library may be old because the docs say that method isn't supported).